# Meaning of "To my dismay/discomfort/surprise"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

I have come across such sentences many times. And i do the last words' meaning too , but i don't get "to my's" meaning.

Comment: to -> towards -> contributing to.  Hence the "much" in "much to my dismay".

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem too. It is kind of a weird construction. 
If you say,

> She had gained five pounds over the winter, much to her chagrin/dismay/etc.

Which means

> Because she had gained five pounds over the winter, she experienced
>   chagrin/dismay/discomfort.

Another example,

> To my surprise, he didn't come to my birthday party.

Which means

> Because he didn't come to my birthday party, I was surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not astonished that sentence introductions such as

to my surprise/astonishment/delight/horror etc

may sound a bit foreign to some. Actually this is a Latin formula, called dativus finalis, describing the effect. Even students who learn Latin have to learn such formulas as something special.

Such literary sentence introductions are not infrequent, but a good term for these formulas is lacking. The Longman Dictionary DCE has these expressions in "to", no. 16 and explains "someone's reaction/or feeling to an event". So one might invent the term "dative of reaction".